# Como cadastrar uma foto usando UploadedFile do primefaces?consegui guardar a foto dentro da variavel foto mas nao consigo salvar ela no banco

Tags: java, primefaces, hibernate

Mensagem do console:

```
set 02, 2015 11:05:01 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) para o contexto '/restaurante'
set 02, 2015 11:05:01 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
set 02, 2015 11:05:02 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
set 02, 2015 11:05:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 02, 2015 11:05:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
set 02, 2015 11:05:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 4091 ms
Hibernate: select produto0_.id as id1_7_, produto0_.categoria_id as categori6_7_, produto0_.image as image2_7_, produto0_.nome as nome3_7_, produto0_.quantidade as quantida4_7_, produto0_.valor as valor5_7_ from Produto produto0_
Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_0_ from Categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_ from Categoria categoria0_
Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_ from Categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.id=?
>>>>>>>> uploaed file: org.primefaces.model.NativeUploadedFile@44bda584
Hibernate: insert into Produto (categoria_id, image, nome, quantidade, valor) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_ from Categoria categoria0_
```

Aqui no console estou imprimindo a foto que foi armazenada na variável foto mas não sei como salvar ela no banco.

Bean

```
Classe ProdutoBean:

    package bean;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import dao.CategoriaDAO;
import dao.ProdutoDAO;
import domain.Categoria;
import domain.Produto;
import util.FacesUtil;

@ManagedBean(name = "produtoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ProdutoBean implements Serializable {

    private Produto produtoCadastro = new Produto();
    private List<Produto> listaProdutos;
    private List<Produto> listaProdutosFiltrados;

    private String acao;
    private Long codigo;

    private List<Categoria> listaCategoria;

    private UploadedFile foto;

    public UploadedFile getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(UploadedFile foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public Produto getProdutoCadastro() {
        return produtoCadastro;
    }

    public void setProdutoCadastro(Produto produtoCadastro) {
        this.produtoCadastro = produtoCadastro;
    }

    public List<Produto> getListaProdutos() {
        return listaProdutos;
    }

    public void setListaProdutos(List<Produto> listaProdutos) {
        this.listaProdutos = listaProdutos;
    }

    public List<Produto> getListaProdutosFiltrados() {
        return listaProdutosFiltrados;
    }

    public void setListaProdutosFiltrados(List<Produto> listaProdutosFiltrados) {
        this.listaProdutosFiltrados = listaProdutosFiltrados;
    }

    public String getAcao() {
        return acao;
    }

    public void setAcao(String acao) {
        this.acao = acao;
    }

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public List<Categoria> getListaCategoria() {
        return listaCategoria;
    }

    public void setListaCategoria(List<Categoria> listaCategoria) {
        this.listaCategoria = listaCategoria;
    }

    public void salvar() {
        try {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>> uploaed file: " + foto);
            if (foto != null) {
                produtoCadastro.setImage(foto.getContents());
            }

            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
            produtoDAO.salvar(produtoCadastro);

            produtoCadastro = new Produto();

            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Produto Cadastrado com sucesso");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao incluir o Produto" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void novo() {
        produtoCadastro = new Produto();

    }

    public void carregarPesquisa() {
        try {
            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
            listaProdutos = produtoDAO.listar();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar os Produtos" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void carregarCadastro() {
        try {
            if (codigo != null) {
                ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
                produtoCadastro = produtoDAO.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
            } else {
                produtoCadastro = new Produto();
            }
            CategoriaDAO categoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO();
            listaCategoria = categoriaDAO.listar();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao incluir o Produto" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void excluir() {
        try {
            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
            produtoDAO.excluir(produtoCadastro);

            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Produto excluido com sucesso");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao incluir o Produto" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void editar() {
        try {
            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
            produtoDAO.editar(produtoCadastro);

            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Produto Editado com sucesso");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao incluir o Produto" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

DAO

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import domain.Produto;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class ProdutoDAO {
    public void salvar(Produto produto) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;

        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.save(produto);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            if (transacao != null) {
                transacao.rollback();
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Produto> listar() {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Produto> produtos = null;

        try {
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Produto.listar");
            produtos = consulta.list();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return produtos;
    }

    public Produto buscarPorCodigo(Long id) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Produto produto = null;

        try {
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Produto.buscarPorCodigo");
            consulta.setLong("id", id);

            produto = (Produto) consulta.uniqueResult();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return produto;
    }

    public void excluir(Produto produto) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;

        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.delete(produto);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            if (transacao != null) {
                transacao.rollback();
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }

    public void editar(Produto produto) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.update(produto);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            if (transacao != null) {
                transacao.rollback();
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Domain
Produto

```
package domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Produto.listar", query = "SELECT produto FROM Produto produto"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Produto.buscarPorCodigo", query = "SELECT produto FROM Produto produto WHERE produto.id = :id") })
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float valor;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer quantidade;

    @Lob
    private byte[] image;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Categoria categoria;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Float getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Float valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean hasimage() {
        return this.image != null && this.image.length > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produto [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", valor=" + valor + ", quantidade=" + quantidade + ", image=" + image + ", categoria="
                + categoria + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <!--Nome da Aplicação -->
    <display-name>Restaurante</display-name>

    <!--Arquivo Principal da aplicação -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/principal.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Configuração do Servlet do JSF -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Tema do PrimeFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>start</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Carregamento do Contexto do hibernate -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>util.ContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Para salvar imagens -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

ProdutoCadastro.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form id="frmProdutoCad" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:toolbar>
            <f:facet name="left">
                <h:outputText value="Produtos" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:toolbar>

        <h:panelGrid id="pnlProdutosCadDados" columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
            <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50"
                value="#{produtoBean.produtoCadastro.nome}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="valor:" />
            <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50"
                value="#{produtoBean.produtoCadastro.valor}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="quantidade:" />
            <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50"
                value="#{produtoBean.produtoCadastro.quantidade}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Foto" for="foto" />
            <p:fileUpload id="foto" value="#{produtoBean.fotoCarro}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Categoria:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{produtoBean.produtoCadastro.categoria}"
                converter="categoriaConverter"
                disabled="#{produtoBean.acao == 'Excluir'}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione uma Categoria" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{produtoBean.listaCategoria}"
                    var="categoria" itemValue="#{categoria}"
                    itemLabel="#{categoria.nome}" />
                <f:validateBean />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="5">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo" actionListener="#{produtoBean.novo}"
                update=":frmProdutoCad:pnlProdutosCadDados"
                rendered="#{produtoBean.acao == 'Novo'}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{produtoBean.salvar}"
                update=":msgGlobal :frmProdutoCad:pnlProdutosCadDados"
                rendered="#{produtoBean.acao == 'Novo'}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Excluir"
                actionListener="#{produtoBean.excluir}" update=":msgGlobal"
                rendered="#{produtoBean.acao == 'Excluir'}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Editar"
                actionListener="#{produtoBean.editar}" update=":msgGlobal"
                rendered="#{produtoBean.acao == 'Editar'}" />
            <p:button value="Voltar"
                outcome="/pages/produtoPesquisa.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

ProdutoPesquisa.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{produtoBean.carregarPesquisa}"
            type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form>
        <p:toolbar>
            <f:facet name="left">
                <h:outputText value="Produtos" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado."
            value="#{produtoBean.listaProdutos}"
            filteredValue="#{produtoBean.listaProdutosFiltrados}"
            paginator="true" rows="6" var="produto">
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:button value="Novo"
                    outcome="/pages/produtoCadastro.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">

                    <f:param name="produtoacao" value="Novo" />
                </p:button>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Nome: " filterBy="#{produto.nome}"
                sortBy="#{produto.nome}">
                <h:outputText value="#{produto.nome}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Opções">

                <p:button value="Excluir"
                    outcome="/pages/produtoCadastro.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
                    <f:param name="produtoacao" value="Excluir" />
                    <f:param name="produtocod" value="#{produto.id}" />
                </p:button>

                <p:button value="Editar"
                    outcome="/pages/produtoCadastro.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
                    <f:param name="produtoacao" value="Editar" />
                    <f:param name="produtocod" value="#{produto.id}" />
                </p:button>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

Comment: Não acredito que seja uma melhor abordagem ter que gravar a imagem no banco de dados, porque imagem pesa muito, há não ser que seja por um proposito muito especifico, a maioria gravar somente o caminho no banco e a imagem na pasta externa.

Comment: Estou tentando gravar no banco pois é um projeto acadêmico, e quando comecei a desenvolver ele eu tive algumas duvidas se iria gravar no banco ou o caminho da imagem, e achei melhor começar tentado gravar no banco primeiro e caso desse muitos problemas posteriormente eu iria tentar gravar o caminho da imagem, muito obrigado pela dica @wladyband

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada aqui lucas.

```
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{produtoBean.fotoCarro}"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" sizeLimit="5000000"
                fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|jpe?g|png)$/" id="upload" />
```

Repara que *fileUploadListener* aponta para o atributo, que no seu caso seria `fotoCarro`, isso no arquivo `xhtml`.

No *ManageBean* uma vez usei assim.

```
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    arquivo = new Arquivo();

    arquivo.setNome(event.getFile().getFileName());

    arquivo.setTipo(event.getFile().getContentType());

    arquivo.setConteudo(event.getFile().getContents());

    NotificarUsuario.mostrarMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Upload", event.getFile().getFileName()
            + " foi subido com sucesso.");

}
```

aqui peguei a imagem que veio no *event*.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda vou tentar colocar o que vocês sugeriram.